# How to refer to an XSLT variable when the name of that variable is the value of another variable

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:value-of select="$variable1"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$variable2"/>
```

variable1 will be the value of $variable2. how do i do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There certainly is a better way of handling your problem. Please, *edit* the question and explain your problem. Provide the source XML document (a small one) and the exact wanted result from the transformation. Also, please, explain any rules/constraints that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. What you can do is something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Dictionary mapping names to values -->
  <xsl:variable name="dict">
    <value name="var1">1</value>
    <value name="var2">2</value>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Name of the value in 'variable1' -->
    <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="'var1'"/>
    <!-- Get the value in 'variable2' using 'variable1' -->
    <xsl:variable name="variable2" select="msxsl:node-set($dict)/value[@name=$variable1]"/>
    <root>
      <xsl:text>variable2: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$variable2"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`msxsl:node-set` is a Microsoft-specific extension to convert fragments to node-sets. If you are using a non-Microsoft processor there should be an equivalent function available.

Comment: is this the same for xsl parameters?

Comment: @user2184503: yes, exactly the same for parameters

Answer (score 0):

As with most programming languages, XSLT variable names are not accessible at run-time.

So, explain why you want to do this - what problem are you trying to solve - and we can show you the right way to solve it.